# How do you uninstall the plugin manager for vim vim-plug?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I know how to uninstall plugins, but how do I actually delete the plugin manager?

Answer (score 0):

You follow the instructions found in the plugin manager's `README.md`, but in reverse.

Case in point…

1. You are told to download a file to a specific location: delete it.
2. You are told to put plugins in a `plugged` directory: delete it.
3. You are told to add a "vim-plug section" to your `vimrc`: delete it.
4. And so on.